# Use Google Sheets API to conditionally update a subset of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a desktop application that is used to edit a table of data. Each row tracks it's most recent change via a timestamp.
Also, there is a Google Spreadsheet that contains that table of data and other people directly use that in the browser to edit the data. On the spreadsheet runs an onEdit script which updates the last-changed timestamp per row.

The desktop app now uses the Google Spreadsheet API to download the sheet and merge the data into the local data by only using rows with a newer timestamp, and this works fine.

I want to add the option to let the desktop app write it's data automatically to the Google Spreadsheet, but to not overwrite all rows, but only those who have an older timestamp.

I have a working version which overwrites all data in the Spreadsheet using the spreadsheets.values.update API, but I don't see how to add a condition to which rows are actually written.

Ideally, the solution would avoid downloading the data, merging it locally and then overwriting the Spreadsheet completely as the data can get quite big and that process would take a long time and would need to limit access to the Spreadsheet while updating in order to not lose changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it is not possible to do what you are intending to do. You would have to do a workaround like for example checking if the timestamps are the same before updating the Spreadsheet.

### Docs

For more info check these docs:

- [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)
- [REST Resource: spreadsheets.values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange).
- [ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption).

Comment: This does assume that the data in the spreadsheet does stay the way it is since last pulling the sheet to the desktop app, since I cannot know if a timestamp is outdated only offline (There will be concurrent use of Browser and Desktop-App). I want to avoid having to pull the sheet, to the data-merging local then push the sheet. I would like to know if the Google-Sheets API can somehow handle the data-merging based on the timestamps.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not possible to do what you are intending to do. You would have to do a workaround like for example checking if the timestamps are the same before updating the Spreadsheet

Comment: Okay. Good to know. That is exactly what I wanted to know. If you edit that to your answer I will mark it as solved, as "not possible" is in my opinion a valid answer.